# Inequality resulted from $f''$ bounded

Tags: integration, analysis, derivatives

> Let $f$ of $C^2$ class in $[-a,a]$ with $a>0$, and let $M=\sup_{x\in[-a,a]}|f''(x)|$.
>
> Prove that for all $x\in[-a,a]$ we have $|f'(x)|\leq\dfrac{1}{2a}|f(a)-f(-a)|+\dfrac{a^2+x^2}{2a}M$

I tried using various methods such as a Taylor expansion with integral remainder, and integrating from $-a$ to $t$, and from $t$ to $a$ for all $t\in[a,b]$ in the inequality $|f''(x)|\leq M$, though it seems that there is something tricky that I am not seeing.

Comment: I'd be shocked if the first step weren't to apply the mean value theorem to the entire interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is "routine", though many would reasonably demand justification, to show that one can assume without loss of generality that $ M = a = 1 $ and that $ f(1) = f(-1) = 0 $.  I will say a few words about this in the way of justification.  For any $ f $ satisfying the assumptions of the problem, one can consider a new function $ g(x) = s f(x / t) + rx + u $ for suitable scalars $ r, s, t, u $ satisfying $ g(-1) = g(1) = 0 $ and $ \sup |g''(t)| = 1 $.  Thus if we can prove the corresponding inequality for such functions, then (the reader should confirm) translating back to the original domain yields the desired inequality.  The problem thus reduces to proving, for such $ g $,
$$
|g'(x)| \leq (x^2 + 1)/2, \qquad x \in [-1,1]
$$
Fix $ x^* \in [-1,1] $ and let $ h(x) = g'(x) $.  We can frame this problem as an optimal control problem.  We are trying to maximize $ |h(x^*)| $ subject to the constraints $ |h'(x)| \leq 1 $ and $ \int_{-1}^{1}{h(x)\,\mathrm{d}x} = 0 $.  The first of these constraints is $ M \leq 1 $ and the second is $ g(-1) = g(1) $ (after applying the fundamental theorem of calculus).

I am confident that this control problem has a piecewise-linear solution $ h $ with the desired $ h(x^*) = ((x^*)^2 + 1)/2 $ but have not completed the computation yet.  Will edit soon but thought this was reasonable progress.

**Edit (my flight just landed, lol)**: Using the above notation, one has
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(a) - f(-a) &= \int_{-a}^{a}{f'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x} \\
&\geq \int_{-a}^{a}{(f'(x^*) - M|x-x^*|)\, \mathrm{d}x} \\
&= 2a f'(x^*) - M(a^2 + (x^*)^2)
\end{aligned}
$$
whence, solving for $f'(x^*) $, the inequality follows.  Translating to [-1,1] turned out not important.

Comment: Wow that was beautiful reasoning. It came out to be much simpler than what I've thought. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you.  The idea to compare to $ f(x^*) - |x - x^*| $ came from considering the optimal control problem, so I'm glad I included that work even though it was not necessary to the eventual proof.

Comment: I'm glad that you've put the extra work at the beginning. It made me understand your thought process that lead you to the eventual proof. Although, there is one thing that I didn't quite understand. How can you justify that for all $f$ satisfying the assumptions of the problem, we can consider a function $g$ with $g(x)=sf(\frac{x}{t}) + rx + u$ ?

Comment: $ r $ and $ u $ terms do not affect the second derivative but allow you to adjust the values of the function at the endpoints so that $ g(-a) = 0 = g(a) $.  This adjustment turns out to preserve the inequality.  Sorry to pull a "Fermat" on you here, but I don't feel like elaborating more than that.  It's a decent exercise though, as noted, not necessary to solve the problem.